# (react) Dynamic URLs, can't render the data I want

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

I'm almost there but still can't manage to send me the data.

I have my data component that render a list of blog posts and my router targeting the index and title

```
//Blockblock.js
const blogData = this.state.blogData.map((value) =>
            value.map((val, idx) =>                                                       
                <BlogBlock 
                    link={val.title.toString().toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")} 
                    title={val.title}
                    subtitle={val.subtitle}
                    thumb={val.thumb}
                    idx={idx}
                />            
            )
        )  

//Blockblock.js
const BlogBlock = (props) => {                
    return (
        <div className={`blog-post post-${props.idx}`}>            
            <Link to={`blog/${props.idx}/${props.link}`}>
                <Img loader={<span className="loading-img">loading....</span>} src={`http://brittdepetter.com/images/${props.thumb}`} alt={props.title} />
                <h3>{props.title}<span><br />{props.subtitle}</span></h3>
            </Link>  
        </div>                        
    )   
}
//app.js
<Route path='/blog/:blogId/:blogTitle' component={BlogPost} />
```

and finally I have my blockpost component, i'm matching the URLs but how do I pass the props to render the data like the images, etc?

````
BlockPost.js
const BlogPost =({match, location}) => {                   
    const { params:{ blogId, blogTitle } } = match;
    return (                          
        <div>                                        
            <h2>{ props.title }</h2> 
            <div className="textBox boxImg">
                <div className="story-img-box">
                    { props.imgsrc }
                </div>            
                <div>
                    {console.log(props)}
                    {props.body}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    )   
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pass additional props from `BlogBlock` to `BlogPost`, that is not possible without some kind of state management like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) where both components would be able to use shared state.

I'd suggest to refetch your blog based on `blogId` inside `BlogPost` component, because you'll need to handle direct access (if user directly navigates to `/blog/:blogId/:blogTitle` by entering it in url, and not from `BlogBlock`) anyway. Another option is to refetch only if it was direct access, otherwise use data from shared state (based on selection from `BlogBlock` which would be stored in that state).

Comment: so if I refetch the data on my blogPost, how do i set the correct URL to render the correct data?

Comment: You have 2 options - either user will enter in browser something like /blog/10/my-blog-title and you'll have all required info for fetching the blog in BlogPost component (just show loader while fetching). Other option is if user navigates from BlogBlock - there you'll manually redirect him via Link to BlogPost and you can either do the same thing (refetch), or you could store clicked blog in shared state (e.g. Redux) and then take it from that state inside BlogPost component (e.g. in BlogPost - if sharedState.blog not null then use sharedState.blog, else refetch using blogId).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on where you are getting your data (img, etc) from

You could use a React Component, and take advantage of of the lifecycle methods, specifically componentDidMount(). Take a look at link I provided, I think it will be helpful.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html